# Getting error while trying to use contains in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I get array of strings from my client. Then in my webapi i split it as following

```
var splitId = string.Join(",", ids);
```

Then i my Linq query i use above variable

This is my Linq query

```
var query = tableARepository.AsQueryable()

.Where(a=> splitId.Contains(a.Id.ToString()))
.Select(a => new {
    Id = a.Id
,   Name = a.Name
,   FkId = tableBRepository.AsQueryable().Min(b => b.fkid=a.id)
});
```

I get this exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.","

This is because of Contains. How can i fix this error?

Comment: What's the type of `a.Id`? And have you considered the negative implications of just using a comma-separated list? (Imagine there's an ID of "x", and another of "xy" - do you really want the `x` record to match when someone searches for `xy`?)

Comment: @JonSkeet a.Id is integet. I dont have issue with getting different records

Comment: it can't convert `ToString()` to sql

Comment: @Happy: You mean you don't care if the results are wrong? That seems odd - so for integers, if your string ends up as "15,20" that would find records with IDs of 1, 5, 2 and 0 as well. Surely you don't want that.

Comment: If i get comma seperated value as 15,20 then i would offcpurse need 15,20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of converting your `ids` to concatenated string, keep them in a `List<T>/IEnumerable<T>` and then query against that like:

Based on your comment:

> Ids are defined as string[] ids

You should convert them to `IEnumerable<int>` or `List<int>` like:

```
List<int> integerIds = ids.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

and then in your query:

```
var query = tableARepository.AsQueryable()
.Where(a=> integerIds.Contains(a.Id))
```

Just make sure that `ids` contains elements of same type as your table `Id`

The reason you are getting the exception is due to the call to `ToString` in your LINQ query, the provider is trying to convert it under laying data source language *(May be SQL)* but it can't.

Comment: @Happy, `ids` would be an `IEnumerable<T>` since it is used in `string.Join` just leave it like that, just make sure that it holds the same type of data as your `a.Id` field.

Comment: A.id is an integer field

Comment: Ids are defined as string[] ids

Comment: @Happy, you have to convert them to `List<int>` or `IEnumerable<int>` I have modified the code, that should solve the problem